# Each Thread Accessing an Array List in Multithreading Code

Tags: java, multithreading, thread-safety, race-condition

I am working on a project in which I have two tables in a different database with different schemas. So that means I have two different connection parameters for those two tables to connect using JDBC-

Let's suppose below is the config.property file.

```
TABLES: table1 table2

#For Table1
table1.url: jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/garden
table1.user: gardener
table1.password: shavel
table1.driver: jdbc-driver
table1.percentage: 80
table1.columns: COL1,COL2,COl3,Col4,COL5

#For Table2
table2.url: jdbc:mysql://otherhost:3306/forest
table2.user: forester
table2.password: axe
table2.driver: jdbc-driver
table2.percentage: 20
table1.columns: COL10,COL11,COl12,Col13,COL14
```

Below method will read the above `config.properties` file and make a `TableConnectionInfo` object for each tables.

```
private static void readPropertyFile() throws IOException {

    prop.load(LnPRead.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("config.properties"));

    tableNames = Arrays.asList(prop.getProperty("TABLES").trim().split(","));

    for (String arg : tableNames) {

        TableConnectionInfo ci = new TableConnectionInfo();
        ArrayList<String> columns = new ArrayList<String>();

        String table = prop.getProperty(arg + ".table").trim();
        columns = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(prop.getProperty(arg + ".columns").split(",")));

        ci.setTableName(table);
        ci.setColumns(columns);

        tableList.put(arg, ci);
    }
}
```

Below is the `TableConnectionInfo class` that will hold all the `table connection info` for a particular table.

```
public class TableConnectionInfo {

    public String tableName;
    public ArrayList<String> columns;


    public String getTableName() {
        return tableName;
    }

    public void setTableName(String tableName) {
        this.tableName = tableName;
    }

    public ArrayList<String> getColumns() {
        return columns;
    }

    public void setColumns(ArrayList<String> columns) {
        this.columns = columns;
    }
}
```

Now I am creating `ExecutorService` for specified number of threads and passing this `tableList` object (that I created by reading the `config.property file`) to constructor of `Task class` And after that this `tableList` object won't get modified by  any of the threads, only each thread will be accessing the values-

```
// create thread pool with given size
ExecutorService service = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10);

long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
long endTime = startTime + (durationOfRun * 60 * 1000);

for (int i = 0; i < threads; i++) {
    service.submit(new Task(endTime, tableList));
}
```

Below is my Task class that implements Runnable interface

```
class Task implements Runnable {

    private static Random random = new SecureRandom();
    private final long endTime;
    private final LinkedHashMap<String, TableConnectionInfo> tableLists;

    public Task(long endTime, LinkedHashMap<String, TableConnectionInfo> tableList) {
        this.endTime = endTime;
        this.tableLists = tableList;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {

        while (System.currentTimeMillis() <= endTime) {

            .....

            double randomNumber = random.nextDouble() * 100.0;
            TableConnectionInfo table = selectRandomTable(randomNumber);

            /* Below line is Thread Safe right? 
             * And there won't be any issue with it? As I am doing
             * table.getColumns which will returns me an ArrayList of columns
             */
            final String columnsList = getTableColumns(table.getColumns());

            ....
        }
      }

     private String getTableColumns(final List<String> columns) {

      ...

     }
}
```

**Problem Statement:-**

In my above run method, I am trying to access `getColumns` method of a particular Table using `table.getColumns` and each thread will be doing the samething. I am not sure whether that is thread safe or not. And it won't cause me any problem like Race conditions or other issues. Any thoughts will be of great help.

Answer (score 0):

This is technically thread safe as long as the underlying ArrayList doesn't change after initial construction.  Each thread in this case will reference the same instance of ArrayList.

If there are plans in the future to make these table columns mutable it would lead to issues.  In the case of mutablility of this list I would either construct a new list and pointer swap or use a java.util.concurrent.* class to hold your list of columns.